# SWIG version check?

Tags: python

Is there any command line check for the version of SWIG ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I get:

```
$ swig -version

SWIG Version 1.3.40

Compiled with g++ [i686-pc-linux-gnu]
Please see http://www.swig.org for reporting bugs and further information
```

Did you mean something else?

```
$ swig -version | perl -nae 'print "$F[2]\n" if /SWIG Version/i;'
1.3.40
```

Comment: swig -version is just fine ! Thanks ..... funnily it was not working my computer...now it does !